# URL Rewrite Using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I wan to redirect on of my url using htaccess file 
http://www.doamin.com/pages/add/ 
to 
http://www.doamin.com/req/

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/pages/add/(.*) http://www.doamin.com/req/$1 [R]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this here:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/packages/add/$ /req/ [L,R]
```

See also the [official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).